# dbcontext sin usar entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, entity-framework

Buen día, estoy trabajando en una aplicación MVC con visual studio C# el problema es que no quisiera usar entity framework, prefiero  usar store procedure sin embargo si me interesa poder trabajar directamente con listas de objetos  por ejemplo

```
using (var db = new DbContext(CONNECTION_NAME))
{
   db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
   SqlParameter[] parametros = new SqlParameter[2];
   parametros[0] = new SqlParameter("@PAIIDCEDULA", idCedula);
   parametros[1] = new SqlParameter("@PAIIDPROYECTO ", idProyecto);
   res = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("CEDULA.SPWEBVALIDADATOSGENERALES @PAIIDCEDULA,@PAIIDPROYECTO", parametros).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

me gustaría poder hacer eso sin la necesidad de emplear entity en mi proyecto

¿Alguna sugerencia? de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: En ese caso, utiliza ADO.net y llenas el resultado de manera tradicional :D

Comment: queres usar linq sobre las listas que te devuelva?

Comment: Quizas este proyecto le interese : https://www.nuget.org/packages/noef/

Comment: Este es el repositorio. Pruebelo. https://github.com/arsoftcr/noef Tal vez le sirva